# association between entities - EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm a beginner with EF and although I have managed to use it successfully before, I can't understand a simple problem I'm facing right now.

I have the following tables in my project.

**MessageUser Table**

```
        public MessageUser()
    {
        this.Conversation = new HashSet<Conversation>();
    }
    public int MessageUserID { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Conversation> Conversation { get; set; }
```

**ChatMessage Table**

```
    public class ChatMessage
{
    public int ChatMessageID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool DeliveryStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public int ConversationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConversationID")]
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
}
```

**Conversation Table**

```
    public class Conversation
{
    public Conversation()
    {
        ChatMessages = new List<ChatMessage>();
        MessageUsers = new List<MessageUser>();
    }
    public int ConversationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MessageUser> MessageUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
}
```

The 'ChatMessage' table and 'Conversation' table have a one-many relationship whereas 'Conversation' and 'MessageUser' have many-many relationship.
I'm trying to save the data as follows:

```
        DataModel db = new DataModel();
        List<MessageUser> ConnectedUsers = db.MessageUsers.ToList();
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage { CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, DeliveryStatus = true, Message = "Hello My name is Mujtaba", Username = "Mujtaba" };
        Conversation conversation = new Conversation();
        conversation.ChatMessages.Add(message);
        conversation.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var user in ConnectedUsers)
        {
            conversation.MessageUsers.Add(user);
        }
```

What I'm trying to understand is, when I add a 'MessageUser' to the collection property of 'Conversation', why isn't an inverse relation is established? What I mean to say is, after I add the entity to the collection, that entity's collection property should also show the object in it's collection to which is was added.

[image]

In the image above, the collection property of the entity which was added to 'Conversation' table has 0 'Conversation' objects. Is it supposed to be this way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Entity framework is lazy by default,how about trying to include the Conversation when you fetch the MessageUsers. i.e something like this          List<MessageUser> ConnectedUsers = db.MessageUsers.Include(x=>x.Conversation)ToList();

Comment: Oh yeah this works :) The association was set after saving the object to the database. It doesn't really matter much though whether the association is reflected or not. But thanks for your help :) Be sure to write in the comment below so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework is lazy by default,how about trying to include the Conversation when you fetch the MessageUsers. i.e something like this

```
List<MessageUser> ConnectedUsers = db.MessageUsers.Include(x=>x.Conversation)ToList()
```

As you pointed out in the comment,the association/mapping is all good and that's the way EF works by default(being lazy).